# Unable to cast object of type '<>d__6' to type 'System.Object[]'

Tags: c#, static, yield-return

I'm trying to lazy load (extension with yield return) the rows in a 2D object array. I get the following error:

> c# Unable to cast object of type '<>d__6' to type 'System.Object[]'.

The exception occurs on this line found in the `Parse` method:

```
yield return (TSource) conversion(o);
```

I don't understand why `C#` thinks the return value is `<>d__6` instead of `Object[]`. I normally program in `VB.NET` so I don't think I'm understanding the nuances of `C#`. What am I doing wrong? I looked at the other similar questions/answers but am still confused.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Parse<TSource>(this object[,] array
        , Func<IEnumerable<object[]>, IEnumerable<TSource>> conversion
        , int rowStart, int columnStart, int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {

        IEnumerable<object[]> o 
            = array.ForEachRow(rowStart, columnStart, rowCount, columnCount);

        yield return (TSource) conversion(o);

    }
```

ForEachRow method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> ForEachRow(this object[,] array, 
               int rowStart, int columnStart, int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {

        object[] array1d=new object[columnCount];
        for (int row = rowStart; row < rowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int column = columnStart; column < columnCount; column++)
            {
                array1d[column] = array[row, column];
            }
            yield return (object[]) array1d;
        }
    }
```

I know this question has been asked before, but the other answers didn't make sense to me unfortunately (I program in VB mostly).

**Code you can use to compile and test (In `VB.NET`):**

Basically I'm getting a 2D object array from Excel and wanting to put it in a class and use Linq to evaluate.

```
 Dim oData As Object(,) = {{"OrderDate", "Region", "Rep", "Item", "Units", "Unit Cost", "Total"} _
        , {New DateTime(2011, 1, 6), "East", "Jones", "Pencil", 95, 1.99, 189.05} _
        , {New DateTime(2011, 1, 23), "Central", "Kivell", "Binder", 50, 19.99, 999.5} _
        , {New DateTime(2011, 2, 9), "Central", "Jardine", "Pencil", 36, 4.99, 179.64} _
        , {New DateTime(2011, 2, 26), "Central", "Gill", "Pen", 27, 19.99, 539.73} _
        , {New DateTime(2011, 3, 15), "West", "Sorvino", "Pencil", 56, 2.99, 167.44} _
        }

    Dim clsSales = oData.Parse(Of SaleOrder)(Function(o As Object()) New SaleOrder( _
                                         If(IsDate(o(0)), o(0), #1/1/1900#) _
                                         , o(1).ToString _
                                         , o(2).ToString _
                                         , o(3).ToString _
                                         , If(IsNumeric(o(4)), CInt(o(4)), 0) _
                                         , If(IsNumeric(o(5)), o(5), 0) _
                                         ), 1, 0, oData.GetUpperBound(0), 6)

    For Each cls In clsSales
        Console.WriteLine(cls.ToString)
    Next
```

**Where the class is:**

```
 Class SaleOrder

Public Sub New(ByVal date_ As Date, ByVal region_ As String, ByVal rep As String, ByVal item_ As String, ByVal units As Integer _
               , ByVal cost As Double)

    OrderDate = date_
    Region = region_
    Representative = rep
    Item = item_
    UnitCount = units
    UnitCost = cost

End Sub

Public OrderDate As DateTime
Public Region As String
Public Representative As String
Public Item As String
Public UnitCount As Integer = 5
Public UnitCost As Double
Public ReadOnly Property Total() As Double
    Get
        Return UnitCount * UnitCost
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}", OrderDate, Region, Representative, Item, UnitCount, UnitCost, Total)
End Function

End Class
```

**Final Solution**

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Parse<TSource>(this object[,] array
        , Func<object[], TSource> conversion
        , int rowStart, int columnStart, int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {

        for (int row = rowStart; row < rowCount; row++)
        {
            object[] array1d = new object[columnCount];
            for (int column = columnStart; column < columnCount; column++)
            {
                array1d[column] = array[row, column];
            }
            yield return conversion(array1d);
        }

    }
```

Comment: In which line you get exception?

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. There's a lot going on here, and we don't even know what `TSource` is or what your conversion delegate does. It's also very unclear why you're casting `array1d` to `object[]` when that's its type already...

Comment: OK, updated with the line of code that I get the error in and deleted some of the code that isn't pertinent.

Comment: Is the error you are getting at *compile time* or *runtime*?  You keep calling it an exception, but exceptions only happen at runtime; compiler errors happen at compile time.

Comment: Note that in `ForEachRow` you yield the same array over and over again while mutating it.  You...probably shouldn't do that.  You should move the creation of `array1d` to inside the first `for` loop.

Comment: @EricLippert You can copy/paste the code into the editor and compile it.  It compiles just fine.  It's a runtime error.

Comment: @EricLippert, It happens at runtime.

Comment: Sure, will do. You guys are going so fast I'm having a hard time keeping up.

Comment: @EricLippert OK, got the code up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`o` is an `IEnumerable<object[]>`.

`conversion(o)` is an `IEnumerable<TSource>`.  You are converting a sequence of objects into a sequence of `TSource` items.

You then cast that `IEnumerable<TSource>` to `TSource`.  You're basically saying, "Treat this sequence of `TSource` items as a single `TSource` item."  What the runtime is telling you is that, "I'm not allowed to treat that sequence of items as a `TSource` item, because that's not what it is.

What you almost certainly want to *actually* do is just replace the last line with:

```
return conversion(o);
```

You have a sequence of `TSource` items, and that's exactly what you need to return.  You were overthinking it by trying to use an iterator block.

If you really, really want to use an iterator block, then you need to yield each item in the sequence, like this:

```
foreach (TSource item in conversion(o))
    yield return item;
```

But why bother.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out your answer and mark correct if I get it working.

Answer (score 5):

With all the information in the comments it is now clear what is going on here. Let's make a much simpler repro:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tiger> Parse()
{
  object obj = ForEachRow();
  yield return (Tiger) obj;
}

public static IEnumerable<Tiger> ForEachRow()
{
  yield return new Tiger();
}
```

OK, what does the compiler do with the bottom method?  It rewrites it like this:

```
class ForEachRowEnumerable : IEnumerable<Tiger>
{
    ... a class which implements an IEnumerable<Tiger> 
    that yields a single tiger...
}

public static IEnumerable<Tiger> ForEachRow()
{
  return new ForEachRowEnumerable();
}
```

So now what does the first method do?

You call ForEachRow. That returns a new ForEachRowEnumerable. You convert that to object. You then cast the object to Tiger. But ForEachRowEnumerable is not a tiger; it is a class that will give you a sequence of tigers.  So the runtime gives you the error "cannot cast ForEachRowEnumerable to Tiger".

The C# compiler of course does not name that class "ForEachRowEnumerable". It names it `<>d__6` to make sure that it is impossible for you to actually use that class by name.

Comment: Thanks for the example of simple code. In future questions I'll make sure to simplify my code the way you demonstrated.

Comment: @Jon49: You're welcome. Coming up with a much-simplified repro not only will get you better answers here, it will keep you from having to ask the question in the first place. It's another form of Rubber Duck Debugging. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging